# Why getmypid() returns same id in browser but different in Windows CMD

Tags: php

So for some reason I need to write the process ID of my PHP script. 
While doing so I found something that I cant understand.

Every time I execute my script from browser I get same id. (even if I execute the same script in 2 different browsers.)

While running it through CMD (Windows Command Prompt) gives me different ids each time.

So I was just curious as in why the same process id is being assigned to my php script when I execute it through browser?

```
<?php
    echo getmypid() . "</br>";
?>
```

Is there a way to generate different process id from the browser every time I execute a PHP script ?

Comment: Has the page been cached on the browser or server?

Comment: No. As I said even on changing the browser I got the same pid..

Comment: This is due to browser cache, try `Ctrl + Shift + R` you will get new process id every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a php script through the command line, you start a new process each time. So the pid is different.

When you refresh a page on the browser, a single php process handle every requests. The pid is unique and stay the same until you restart the server.

Comment: Hey thanks mate, this sounds right but is there a way I can generate different process id every time I run a script through browser swell?

Comment: not sure of what you want to do, but you have uniqid function to generate uniq ids: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: Well what I want to do is write resume script excuted by a cron job that checks if the pid which was generated by main php script has been stopped or not and if so resume it again.

Comment: you can write a lock file somewhere at the begining of your cron. At the end if everything is ok, delete the file. look for the file at the start of your cron to know if a previous execution failed (or is still running...)